# This is not working in chrome only. Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Bootstrap Datetimepicker not working in chrome browser only. if we navigate to other tab or inspect the web page it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/Venkatesh_srikanth/e2mwv05v/11/

```
[Fiddle: My Bootstrap Datetimepicker Code][1]
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Venkatesh_srikanth/e2mwv05v/11/

Comment: What do you mean navigate to other tab or inspect ? And then it works ?What does not work can you right the codeblock that doesn't work?

Comment: The above mentioned Fiddle not work normally when open in the Chrome browser. after opening the browser I try to click the field but it doesn't work. I open the new tab in the browser or inspect the web page and click the date picker field it works. (Only in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

`$( document ).ready(function() {});`

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model `(DOM)` is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Comment: The above fiddle is working perfectly for me in chrome try to update your browser

Comment: Fiddle has sperate engine that's why it works fine I think :(

Comment: can you please share your chrome version

Comment: yep i am using latest version 60.0.3112.113

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153104/discussion-between-l-g-karolos-and-venkatesh-srikanth).

Comment: Here the Result :( I am using bootstrap 4 alpha 6. So that it doesn't work for me https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/2169

Comment: I added the answer if someone has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally the answer was :

well this is a `bootstrap 3` library and your using `bootstrap 4` alpha 6 so try another library like this one [bootstrap-4-datepicker](https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4)